# Saber o tipo de retorno de um dado

Tags: python-3.x, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Estou com um problema com o tipo de retorno de um dado em python. Primeiro estava tentando :

```
    >>> type(record[0][keys[2]])
<class 'Bio.Entrez.Parser.StringElement'>
```

tentei verificar pelo `if`

```
>>> type(record[0][keys[2]])is list
>>> type(record[0][keys[2]])is string
>>> type(record[0][keys[2]])is array
```

todos retornam `Falso`

já comparei também com o tipo inteiro `'Bio.Entrez.Parser.StringElement'`
e também da `Falso`. Então mudei a abortagem vou ver se existe a palavra do tipo de string eu quero no retono `<class 'Bio.Entrez.Parser.StringElement'>` da função `type`  para fazer essa comparação tenho que pegar a string dentro de `< >` para que eu faça essa comparação? Como fazer isso ?

Comment: Você precisa primeiro importar StringElement, depois pode comparar seu objeto com `isinstance(record[0][keys[2]], StringElement)`.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize 'isinstance'.
exemplo:

```
if isinstance(<Object>, <Class>):
    faz qualquer coisa
else:
    faz outra coisa
```

Answer (score 0):

Exprimente fazer assim:

`type(<Objecto>) is <Tipo>`

Por exemplo:

```
type("Eu sou uma String!") is str # => True
```